# What does "getting faded" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I saw this sentence in NCIS tv series :

> The night is young. Let's get faded

What does this mean? *night is young*  and *let's get faded*

Comment: It’s a US slang term [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=faded) can often be a good place to look for slang meanings, but be careful: there’s a lot of nonsense on there as well. In this case, though, the second definition is spot on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*night is young* is an old idiom, Google Ngram has occurrences back to 1804. It means that it's early in the evening, although it's often used facetiously when it's getting late, but the speaker doesn't want to end the evening's activities. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_night_is_young) defines it as:

> It's not very late (at night) and there's plenty of time.

*faded* is more recent slang meaning [high on marijuana](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=faded).

So the sentence you quoted is saying that it's not too late to get stoned.

Answer (score -1):

Faded means either high or drunk. Essentially under the influence of something that has led to a duller/less sharp version of someone's senses. Hence the word Faded

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While answers to old questions are welcome on this site, it is expected that they will be posted only if they add something significant to what is already on the page. What exactly does this answer add to what can be discerned from the one posted three years ago?